# AuiNotebook - Get clicked tab

Tags: python, events, wxpython, wxnotebook

I am currently using some wxPython's AuiNotebook in one of my projects and I have a problem that can't manage to solve. I think there should be a simple solution but can't manage to find it.

I have created a new class derived from `wx.lib.agw.aui.AuiNotebook` and I am trying to get the index of a tab at the moment it's clicked. I wrote something like that:

```
class NewNotebook(wx.lib.agw.aui.AuiNotebook):

    # __init__ function an stuff...

    def OnTabClicked(self, evt):
        index = self.GetSelection()
        print index
        wx.lib.agw.aui.AuiNotebook.OnTabClicked(self, evt)
```

The aim was to capture the index of the tab clicked on and in some cases, have a special behavior, or just perform a regular click otherwise. However, I think that `AuiNotebook.OnTabClicked` actually changes the selection among different things. It would explain why `index` contains the value of the tab that was selected before the click.

I did not a find a way to get the selection of the new tab though. I looked for some information in the captured event but still could not find the one I wanted.

So, does someone know how I can get the selected tab before I call `AuiNotebook.OnTabClicked`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There doesn't seem to be a builtin way to do this. The closest I found was something I helped with on the [wxPython mailing list](https://groups.google.com/forum/?fromgroups=#!topic/wxpython-users/h4IBr7IfSDE), but that had to do with double-clicking.

Here's one workaround that came to me though. When you first show the frame, set some kind of class property to the currently shown tab (i.e. self.currentTab = 0). Then catch the EVT_AUINOTEBOOK_PAGE_CHANGING or EVT_AUINOTEBOOK_PAGE_CHANGED event and update the property. For me, when I catch EVT_AUINOTEBOOK_PAGE_CHANGING, I always get the index of the tab I'm clicking on, at least on Windows.

Comment: Ok. The workaround seems to work fine enough, thanks! I'm still a little disappointed that there isn't any built-in way though, it would have been handier :p

Comment: Yeah, no kidding. I would put in a request on the wxPython-users group. Andrea (the author) may add it if you ask nicely.